# How do I get a Mac like Dock

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I want to get rid of the normal Ubuntu task bar and have a dock displayed at the bottom of my screen. I tried using Cairio Dock but I dont really like it and still could not get rid of the default dock besides putting it on autohide

Comment: Check the Elementary OS (variation of Ubuntu): https://elementary.io/

Comment: For best results, set sensitivity to lowest (far left) and set the "sensitive location" to be the top left corner. Then you'll hardly ever see the default launcher anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Plank Dock to get a Mac like Dock in Ubuntu

```
`sudo apt-get install plank`
```

set the sensitivity to the lowest to avoid the taskbar